# How can I fix the "Syntax Error" on VBA listbox filtering work

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, listbox, filtering

I'm new on VBA and I'm trying to create the VBA `listbox` filtering macro. I found an example and I transferred my data to the lists. But I'm getting a Syntax Error. I don't know the reason and need to fix it.

I think I'm getting the syntax error message from this line:

```
Sheets("liste").Range(ls.Cells(1, 1), ls.Cells(y1, x1)).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy
```

The code:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
Dim ls, rs As Worksheet
Set ls = Sheets("Liste")
Set rs = Sheets("Rapor")
x1 = ls.Range("1:1").End(xlToRight).Column
y1 = ls.Range("A250000").End(xlUp).Row
x2 = rs.Range("1:1").End(xlToRight).Column
y2 = rs.Range("A250000").End(xlUp).Row
rs.Range(rs.Cells(1, 1), rs.Cells(y2, x2)).Clear
rs.Range("N1") = ComboBox1
rs.Range("N2") = TextBox1
Sheets("liste").Range(ls.Cells(1, 1), ls.Cells(y1, x1)).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy
CriteriaRange:=rs.Range ("N1:N2"), CopyToRange:=rs.Range("A1"), Unique:=False
x2 = rs.Range("1:1").End(xlToRight).Column
y2 = rs.Range("A250000").End(lxup).Row

ListBox1.ColumnCount = x2
i = rs.Range(rs.Cells(1, 1), rs.Cells(y2, x2))
ListBox1.List = i
End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

q = Sheets("Liste").Range("1:1").End(xlToRight).Column
w = Sheets("Liste").Range("A250000").End(xlUp).Row
For a = 1 To q
ComboBox1.AddItem Sheets("Liste").Cells(1, a)
Next
ListBox1.ColumnCount = q
i = Sheets("Liste").Range(Sheets("Liste").Cells(1, 1), Sheets("Liste").Cells(w, q))
ListBox1.List = i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax error is because you are missing the comma and line continuation chars (space and underscore) from the end of the line that you mention ... the line needs to read

```
Sheets("liste").Range(ls.Cells(1, 1), ls.Cells(y1, x1)).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
```

The line continuation chars tell the editor that the two physical lines are actually one long line. The alternative (but less good for code readability) is to delete the newline and have `CriteriaRange:=rs.Range ("N1:N2"), CopyToRange:=rs.Range("A1"), Unique:=False` continue immediately on so you would have

```
Sheets("liste").Range(ls.Cells(1, 1), ls.Cells(y1, x1)).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=rs.Range ("N1:N2"), CopyToRange:=rs.Range("A1"), Unique:=False
```

Comment: this filter system only filtering the "text" , how can i filter "text and numeric" ?  Can you help please?

Comment: I (or someone else here on SO) can help you with that also, but you need to ask a new question

Comment: I asked a new question, can you help please?